# Unable to connect remotely to a windbg server, possibly because of a dll version mismatch?

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg

My goal is to control a running instance of WinDbg from another C++ program. I saw that the API [DebugConnectWide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-debugconnectwide) can let you connect remotely to a debug client, so I tried using it and I made sure to start a server from the running windbg client by entering this command:

`.server npipe:pipe=testname`.

I am able to open a 2nd instance of windbg and connect to the first instance remotely by entering the following on the command line arguments:

`-remote npipe:Pipe=sup,Server=DESKTOP-JT5S9BR`.

However when I try to connect programmatically from my C++ console application, I get the following error from the HRESULT: `The server is currently disabled.`

```
#include <dbgeng.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IDebugClient7* debugger = nullptr;

    hr = DebugConnectWide(L"npipe:Pipe=testname,Server=DESKTOP-NAME", IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugger));

    std::getchar();
}
```

I read in the doc that it's important for all of the instances of windbg to have the same version if they want to connect remotely. So it's possible that my problem is related to that. I saw that there are many versions of `dbgeng.dll` and `dbgeng.lib` on my computer, so how can I make sure that my C++ app is running the same version of dbgeng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you need the version of the dbgeng.dll that the server is running

normally installing same windbg versions in server and client and running the application from clients windbg installation folder will work

or you can copy the dbgeng to the local folder where exe is situated

copy c:\prograxxxxxx\dbgeng.dll . to the directory of the executable

here is an example flow on

code that does  DebugConnect()  (Ascii version of DebugConectWide)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbgeng.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dbgeng.lib")
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        IDebugClient *dbgclient = NULL;
        HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
        hr = DebugConnect(argv[1], __uuidof(IDebugClient), (VOID **)&dbgclient);
        if (hr == S_OK && dbgclient != NULL)
        {
            ULONG mask = 0xdeadbeef;
            hr = dbgclient->GetOutputMask(&mask);
            if (hr == S_OK && mask != 0xdeadbeef)
            {
                printf("Outputmask = %x\n", mask);
            }
            printf("hresult = %x\tmask = %x\n", hr, mask);
        }
        printf("hresult = %x\tdbgclient = %p\n", hr, dbgclient);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("usage %s remote connection string", argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiled in x64 as x64 in win10 1803 with vs2017 community dev cmdprompt using

```
cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /EHsc /nologo concliw.cpp /link /release
```

a list of process that has cdb in its command line argument running in local machine

```
server debuggee client and wmic  commandlines 

C:\>whoami
kr\xxxxx

C:\>wmic process get CommandLine /format:list | grep -i cdb
CommandLine=cdb  -server npipe:pipe=windpipe cdb
CommandLine=cdb
CommandLine=cdb  -remote npipe:server=KR,pipe=windpipe
CommandLine=grep  -i cdb
```

copied the correct dbgeng.dll and renamed it as test_dbgeng.dll

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbgeng.dll" .
ren dbgeng.dll test_dbgeng.dll
```

executing the binary renaming back dbgeng.dll and re-executing the binary

```
concliw.exe
usage concliw.exe remote connection string
concliw.exe "npipe:server=KR,pipe=windpipe"
hresult = 8007053d      dbgclient = 0000000000000000

ren test_dbgeng.dll dbgeng.dll

concliw.exe "npipe:server=KR,pipe=windpipe"
Outputmask = 3f7
hresult = 0     mask = 3f7
hresult = 0     dbgclient = 000001FA6B9D2590
```